# Pandas dataframe apply to multiple column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use `apply` function to my DataFrame. 
The apply use a custom function that returns 2 values and that needs to populate the row of 2 columns on my DataFrame.

I put a simple example below:

```
df = DataFrame ({'a' : 10})
```

I wish to create two columns: b and c. 
b equals 1 if a is above 0. 
c equals 1 if a is above 0.

```
def compute_b_c(a):
   if a > 0:
      return 1, 1
   else:
      return 0,0
```

I tried this but it returns key error:

```
df[['b', 'c']] = df.a.apply(compute_b_c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with `DataFrame` constructor,also `1,1` and `0,0` are like tuples `(1,1)` and `(0,0)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'a' : [10, -1, 9]})

def compute_b_c(a):
   if a > 0:
      return (1,1)
   else:
      return (0,0)

df[['b', 'c']] = pd.DataFrame(df.a.apply(compute_b_c).tolist())
print (df)
    a  b  c
0  10  1  1
1  -1  0  0
2   9  1  1
```

**Performance**:

```
#10k rows
df = pd.DataFrame ({'a' : [10, -1, 9] * 10000})

In [79]: %timeit df[['b', 'c']] = pd.DataFrame(df.a.apply(compute_b_c).tolist())
22.6 ms ± 285 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [80]: %timeit df[['b', 'c']] = df.apply(lambda row: compute_b_c(row['a']), result_type='expand', axis=1)
5.25 s ± 84.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tested the first solution and it works great.
I am now checking the second one and I am wondering if it is an efficient solution to create a new DataFrame each time and if it is not a costly operation

Comment: @Solal - I think more complicated like seems. Generaly best is use pandas native functions, these are fastest (obviosly). If need custom fuction, it depends of each of them individually.

Comment: @Solal - tested functions with sample function and my second solution was slow, so remove it.

Comment: actually the second function was not working because it kept only the data of the first row computed

Answer (score 0):

Use `result_type` parameter of [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply). Applicable only if you use `apply` function on `df`(DataFrame) and not `df.a`(Series)

```
df[['b', 'c']] = df.apply(lambda row: compute_b_c(row['a']), result_type='expand', axis=1)
```

Comment: result_type is an unexpected keyword argument

Comment: Notice the difference, its `df.apply` and not `df.a.apply`

Comment: @nishant - Unfortunately this method is slow, maybe not very optimalized because rarest used or because DataFrame.apply with `axis=1`.

Comment: @jezrael Yes..in case of large dfs, I will prefer your solution. However just out of curiosity why is series.apply.tolist() faster than df.apply?